# Populate modal with a mysql query reult data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

i have an html page that shows data populated from mysql database.
I give to user choice to edit records. I would like to use a modal form that, when pressed edit, it open up and display data result from mysql db and realated to a certain "id".

Can you help me to achieve this?
Reading on web i've understood that i have to use jquery, but i cannot find a way.
For now i tried as following:

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="edit_grp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit_grpLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="edit_grpLabel">Modifica Interno</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Sequenza Chiamata</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_grp_pos" id="edit_grp_pos" value="<?php echo $row[0]['grp_pos']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Nome</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="edit_grp_name" id="edit_grp_name" value="<?php echo $row[0]['grp_name']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Interno</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="edit_grp_phone" id="edit_grp_phone" value="<?php echo $row[0]['grp_phone']; ?>">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit_edit_grp" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="closeAll()">Modifica</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT 1:
I'am having some tests.
For now 've changed code like this:

`

```
<form method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_grp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit_grpLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="edit_grpLabel">Modifica Interno</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="phone_details">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit_edit_grp" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="closeAll()">Modifica</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

`

`

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_phone_data', function(){
var data_id = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
url:"select.php",
method:"POST",
data:{data_id:data_id},
success:function(data){
$('#phone_details').html(data);
$('#edit_grp').modal('show');
}
});
});
```

`

and select.php

`

```
    <?php  
if(isset($_POST["data_id"]))
{
$output = '';
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","administrator","psw","db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM gruppioxe WHERE id = '".$_POST["data_id"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$output .= '  
<div class="table-responsive">  
<table class="table table-bordered">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$output .= '
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ordine Chiamata</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="'.$row["grp_pos"].'" name="'.$row["grp_pos"].'">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="'.$row["grp_name"].'" name="'.$row["grp_name"].'">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Interno</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="'.$row["grp_phone"].'" name="'.$row["grp_phone"].'">
</div>
</form>
';
}
echo $output;
}
?>
```

`

But still no result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!
i've changed select.php as following:

`

```
$output .= '
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ordine Chiamata</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="grp_pos" name="grp_pos" value="'.$row["grp_pos"].'">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grp_name" name="grp_name" value="'.$row["grp_name"].'">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Interno</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="grp_phone name="grp_phone" value="'.$row["grp_phone"].'">
</div>
</form>
';
}
echo $output;
```

`